# capybara poltergeist click not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

i dont know how to click link href in capybara poltergeist, i have sample code like this in my testing

```
it "test", :driver => :poltergeist do
  page.find("#link1").click 
end
```

and in my html, i have sample like this

```
<table class="index">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/3" id="link1">hey click me</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

how to click link in capybara poltergeist?
i already try "click_link", "click_button" and any else but still not working

Comment: Are you sure that the `page` variable contains that HTML? Do you get an error? What is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try using

```
 all(:xpath,'//a[@id="link1"]').first.click
```

or
 `find(:xpath,'//a[@id="link1"]').trigger('click')`

If that's ambiguous, you can add on more details such as

`find(:xpath,'//a[@id="link1"]', :text => 'hey click me').trigger('click')`

Comment: This answer worked for me also, but does not address why Capybara would not trigger the link using click_link.  In my case, when using click_link("link1"), the link would be triggered sometimes, randomly, and other times not.

Comment: @vanboom is your page very javascript heavy? when doing .click, the browser is attempting a "human click", when you do trigger('click'). it is using the javascript click. Let me know if that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: FWIW I get these intermittent issues with click_button regularly as well. Our page uses some javascript (two AJAX form field validation calls) and I'm not sure that count as 'heavy' (subjective term really).